# How to set one main activity and populate fragments in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-navigationview

i have one mainactivity and other fragments , what i want is that by using only that single activity , i show a default fragment in activity and then when user click on navigation drawer then fragments according to that item must populate on the same are but with different information , i had searched a lot but not got proper solution for it , i am pasting my mainactivity class here ,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
FragmentTwo.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    private SliderLayout mDemoSlider;

    DrawerLayout drawer;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_right_view);
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    // Handle Right navigation view item clicks here.
                    int id = item.getItemId();
                    Fragment fragment = null;
                    Class fragmentClass = null;


                if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
                    fragmentClass = first.class;

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
                    fragmentClass = secnd.class;

                }    try {
                    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
                item.setChecked(true);

                setTitle(item.getTitle());

                DrawerLayout mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

code for first fragment class is here ,

```
public class first extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public first() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentOne.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static first newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving your problem i am just using your code and doing some improvments ,just use required code in your activity file .

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
///it is required code
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;
        fragment = new Fragmentforslider();
      fragmentClass= FragmentOne.class;
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
    }

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Comment: i m trying for your suggestion